# Database list is empty while creating OLE DB connection crystal reports c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to use Crystal reports and I am trying to create an OLEDB connection so that I can connect to my SQL Database. I am choosing Microsoft OLE DB Procider for SQL Server.

When I give "." and click on the dropdown of Database Selection, It is not giving me any database that is in my local server.  Please find the screenshot below. Can anyone help me with this issue?

[image]

Comment: Please post relevant codes so that we can help you :)

Comment: @zackraiyan, I am using Database expert dialog box to create a connection. I am not using any code for this purpose.

Comment: Have you provided proper credentials to connect to the database server.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya, yeah i am using same credentials for various forms in my project and all of them are working perfectly except for this.